# WordPress which is the right way to enqueue script and style in a php class?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm getting PHP notices like this one:

```
Notice: Function wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. This notice was triggered by the fluid-player-js handle.
```

The piece of code that gives me the notice:

```
public static $index = 0;

private static function loadAssets() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fluid-player-js', self::FP_CDN_CURRENT_URL . '/fluidplayer.min.js', [], false, true);
    wp_enqueue_style('fluid-player-css', self::FP_CDN_CURRENT_URL . '/fluidplayer.min.css');
}

public static function init() {
    static::loadAssets();
    static::initShortcodeToJSMapping();

    add_shortcode('fluid-player', array('FluidPlayerPlugin', 'shortcodeSimple'));
    add_shortcode('fluid-player-extended', array('FluidPlayerPlugin', 'shortcodeExtended'));
    add_shortcode('fluid-player-html-block', array('FluidPlayerPlugin', 'shortcodeHtmlBlock'));
    add_shortcode('fluid-player-multi-res-video', array('FluidPlayerPlugin', 'shortcodeHtmlBlock'));

    //Disabling smart quotes filter for shortcode content
    add_filter('no_texturize_shortcodes', function () {
        $shortcodes[] = 'fluid-player-multi-res-video';
        $shortcodes[] = 'fluid-player-html-block';
        $shortcodes[] = 'fluid-player-extended';
        $shortcodes[] = 'fluid-player';

        return $shortcodes;
    });

    //Disabling line breaks and paragraphs from shortcode content. Could have side effects!
    remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');
}
```

its the Fluid Player plugin from the WordPress.org but last update was 4 years ago and nobody is caring about this small problem.

Anyone knows how to fix? Thank you.

Comment: place your code in a action callback for `wp_enqueue_scripts` etc...  ~  `do_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_function')` Basically your calling it too soon.

Comment: its this plugin here, Im going to try like you said https://wordpress.org/plugins/fluid-player/

Comment: That I don't know about.  But that is typically what that error means.

Comment: As ArtisticPhoenix said above that code is being executed too soon, hence the PHP notice. Try having the `init()` method run with [init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) or with [plugins_loaded](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/). With that being said, that plugin has been abandoned for over 4 years now (at the time of writing). I would advise not using outdated code on any project unless you plan to maintain said code yourself.